# Hide the div when the submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to permanently hide the `<div class="frm_button_submitt" id="hideOnSubmit">` after pressing the submit button

I’m creating a multi-step form, what I mean when the user skips the first step, the div disappears

```html
<div class="frm_submit">
[if back_button]<button type="submit" name="frm_prev_page" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" class="frm_prev_page" [back_hook]>[back_label]</button>[/if back_button]

<!-- When you click here for the first time -->
<button class="frm_button_submit" type="submit" id="toggle" [button_action]>[button_label]</button>

<!-- This div disappears in the following steps -->
<div class="frm_button_submitt" id="hideOnSubmit">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true" tabindex="4"><i class="a-icon a-icon-checkbox"></i><span class="a-label a-checkbox-label">
          Keep me signed in.
          <span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover="{&quot;activate&quot;:&quot;onclick&quot;,&quot;header&quot;:&quot;\&quot;Keep Me Signed In\&quot; Checkbox&quot;,&quot;inlineContent&quot;:&quot;\u003cp>Choosing \&quot;Keep me signed in\&quot; reduces the number of times you're asked to Sign-In on this device.\u003c\/p>\n\u003cp>To keep your account secure, use this option only on your personal devices.\u003c\/p>&quot;}">
            <a id="remember_me_learn_more_link" href="javascript:void(0)" class="a-popover-trigger a-declarative">
              Details
            <i class="a-icon a-icon-popover"></i></a>
          </span>
</span></label>
</div>


[if save_draft]<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="frm_save_draft" [draft_hook]>[draft_label]</a>[/if save_draft]
</div>
```

This is a simple solution, using an enumerator, but I could not implement it, is there someone who can help me to write it correctly and completely

```js
const element = document.getElementById("#");
let clickCount = 0;

element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if(clickCount > 0) return element.style.display = "none";
  
  console.log("Clicked")
  clickCount++;
});
```

Note: The number of clicks next 4 clicks

[image: An image to illustrate the problem]

Comment: Please update the top snippet with javascript instead of posting two non-working snippets. We need to see a [mcve] - also what is the HTML? Some kind of framework?

Comment: I'm working on wordpress, and this is the html code from plugin formidable forms

Comment: You should delegate and use a class. Your js does not work since # is not a valid selector

Comment: Can you give me the complete code?, I am weak in programming

Comment: Not without a [mcve] - I do not understand your code as it is written now.

Comment: This form is plugin by https://wordpress.org/plugins/formidable/

Comment: Sorry, I do not hack wp plugins. Why not ask the developer of the plug-in?

Comment: I gave you the code, you understand, it's not a hack

Comment: As you can seen one wants to answer and the answer you got you do not like so there is something missing from the question

Comment: If you want to hide permanently then why not used remove() method? like using jQuery do $(".frm_button_submitt").remove();

Comment: I do not want to hide it completely, but I want to hide it in the following steps and then return when the page is refreshed

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to manage it.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add('hideTheButton');
  });
})
```

... and then just have a css rule:

```
body.hideTheButton #hideOnSubmit{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: But why does it disappear in the first step only and return in the next steps ?! See the picture to understand what I mean

Comment: Please tell me where to find final form submit. I use formidableforms plugin

Comment: It worked but why does it disappear permanently, when I refresh the page I can't find it until I delete the cookies

Comment: Ok, I was overthinking this. Try this revised solution.

Answer (score 0):

your question code is very clumsy. but you can hide in this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById("hideOnSubmit").style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }
</script>

<div class="frm_submit">
  [if back_button]<button type="submit" name="frm_prev_page" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" class="frm_prev_page"
    [back_hook]>[back_label]</button>[/if back_button]

  <!-- When you click here for the first time -->
  <button class="frm_button_submit" type="submit" id="toggle" [button_action]
    onclick="return hideDiv()">[button_label]</button>

  <!-- This div disappears in the following steps -->
  <div class="frm_button_submitt" id="hideOnSubmit">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true" tabindex="4"><i
        class="a-icon a-icon-checkbox"></i><span class="a-label a-checkbox-label">
        Keep me signed in.
        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover"
          data-a-popover="{&quot;activate&quot;:&quot;onclick&quot;,&quot;header&quot;:&quot;\&quot;Keep Me Signed In\&quot; Checkbox&quot;,&quot;inlineContent&quot;:&quot;\u003cp>Choosing \&quot;Keep me signed in\&quot; reduces the number of times you're asked to Sign-In on this device.\u003c\/p>\n\u003cp>To keep your account secure, use this option only on your personal devices.\u003c\/p>&quot;}">
          <a id="remember_me_learn_more_link" href="javascript:void(0)" class="a-popover-trigger a-declarative">
            Details
            <i class="a-icon a-icon-popover"></i></a>
        </span>
      </span></label>
  </div>
```

Comment: div does not disappear in the following steps, I guess you did not understand my question well